# trying to split homepage into four parts

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to divide my homepage into four even images with no scroll. as you click on the website I would like the four images to fill the entire screen and have no scroll. Here's how far I am now but it's not quite working. Any suggestions?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.containermenu img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="containermenu">
    <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="containermenu">
    <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Code** [Here](https://codepen.io/SteveBarrett/pen/rWMGbo)

Comment: you need body{margin:0;} in your css

Comment: you want this https://jsfiddle.net/3t72a8d3/

Comment: If you put the images this way you'll have to stretch them or cut them if the proportions of the image aren't the same as the screen... What do yo prefer?

Comment: use height:25%; width:auto; css properties

Comment: @jsfiddle.net/3t72a8d3. this is good but do you know a way of the images not stretching?

Comment: Thanks for ye're help!

Answer (score 1):

Right, here is how I would do it. I'd make 4 boxes and position them in each quarter of the screen. Then I'd give each one a background image that is set to stay centred and to cover the entire box.

```css
/* Sizing */
.containermenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

/* Images */
.tl {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bathroom-mosaic-pattern_23-2147497370.jpg);
}
.tr {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-geometric-pattern_23-2147508597.jpg);
}
.br {
  background-image: url(https://images.blogthings.com/whatpatternisyourbrainquiz/pattern-2.jpg);
}
.bl {
  background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5459ec52e4b04d305f68f1ed/t/548a96e1e4b0a10ad41ef12f/1418368738802/Pattern14.jpg?format=1000w);
}

/* Positioning */
.tl,
.tr {
  top: 0
}
.br,
.tr {
  right: 0
}
.bl,
.br {
  bottom: 0
}
.tl,
.bl {
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="containermenu tl"></a>
<a href="#" class="containermenu tr"></a>
<a href="#" class="containermenu br"></a>
<a href="#" class="containermenu bl"></a>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Is your looking ?

.containermenu{width:25%;float:left}
.containermenu img
{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float: left;
}
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hd00hbgv/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain the proportion, you could use the images as backgrounds in CSS and use

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Would that work if I wanted to add a roll over image?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you are trying to use viewport sizing, so you have to set the meta to be available to use it, and `body height` and `width` to 100%,  besides setting `padding` and `margin` to 0 to remove white bordering as @Andrew Bone suggested.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containermenu img{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>The Steve Barrett Collection</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="containermenu"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></div>
    <div class="containermenu"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></div>
    <div class="containermenu"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></div>
    <div class="containermenu"><img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/vgmv80.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways you could to do to achieve this result

**With images**

If you want to work with images you could make use of the
`object-fit: cover` property. The great thing about this is that it acts like the `background-image: cover` but you can set it directly to an image and it doesn't get stretched. There is also a `object-position` property. Sadly this great feature is not fully [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) by the one and only Internet Explorer and even Edge.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/32237/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/30168/pexels-photo-30168.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/164241/pexels-photo-164241.jpeg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/230800/pexels-photo-230800.jpeg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/32237/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/30168/pexels-photo-30168.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/164241/pexels-photo-164241.jpeg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/230800/pexels-photo-230800.jpeg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**With background images**

One small disadvantage is that you have to set the path of the images in the CSS but the big advantage is that you can make use of the `background-size: cover` which is supported in every browser. Here you can also make use of the `nth-child` selector so you don't have to give each div, in this case `.img` a class left, right or something.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container .img{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img:nth-child(1){
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/32237/pexels-photo.jpg);
}

.img:nth-child(2){
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/30168/pexels-photo-30168.jpg);
}

.img:nth-child(3){
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/164241/pexels-photo-164241.jpeg);
}

.img:nth-child(4){
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/230800/pexels-photo-230800.jpeg);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container .img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.img:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/32237/pexels-photo.jpg);
}
.img:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/30168/pexels-photo-30168.jpg);
}
.img:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/164241/pexels-photo-164241.jpeg);
}
.img:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/230800/pexels-photo-230800.jpeg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```